# Thermoelectric cooler working type

Tags: peltier

I have some questions regarding TEC.

1. What if, I *operate* TEC without any cooling fan both side. In this condition for how much time it can run.
2. What if, I *operate* TEC with one cooling fan at cold side and other side is heatsink only.
3. How can I get 0 degree *temperature* continuously using PWM or other *temperature* controller device.

Br//
Deepak

Comment: You need to give more information for #1 & #2, for #3 you use a closed loop system.

Comment: 1 and 3 are questions, but I don't see any question in #2.

Comment: 2 should be 1.b and 1 should be 1.a

Answer (score 0):

Forced air cooling improves thermal conductance or reduces thermal resistance up to 10x at high linear air speed over fins.  Why would want to degrade the performance?

One example might be that you want a beverage cooler and heater with the thermal transfer with good thermal coupling so that the result maximizes the efficiency without thermal losses in the interface.